# How to add an alias IP to a VLAN interface in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, ip, rc, vlan

How can I add an alias to a VLAN interface in FreeBSD?

I tried the following, but it seems to be ignored:

```
# /etc/rc.conf
vlans_igb0="vlan42"
create_args_vlan42="vlan 42"
ifconfig_igb0="up"
ifconfig_vlan42="inet6 2001:db8::42 prefixlen 64 mtu 1500"
ifconfig_vlan42_aliases="\
    inet6 fd00::dead:beef prefixlen 64 \
    inet6 2001:db8::babe:cafe prefixlen 128 \
"
```

After rebooting, only `2001:db8::42` comes up. Any service that is explicitly configured to listen on the alias addresses fails to start.  Running `ifconfig alias inet6 fd00::dead:beef prefixlen 64` after boot and restarting the services works, but I'd like this to work at boot.

Comment: What’s in your `/etc/rc.conf` file?

Comment: I think you have to define each alias seperately

Answer (score 0):

This might explain:

https://mebsd.com/configure-freebsd-servers/freebsd-ifconfig-in-rc-conf-new-style.html

what I understood reading that: the aliases option is probably not supported with v6 addresses.